# Invalid read when running under valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
valgrind-3.8.1
c89
```

Hello,

```
==1160== Invalid read of size 1
==1160==    at 0x8048C94: get_input_values (parse_cmd_input.c:278)
==1160==    by 0x8048BA0: parse_input (parse_cmd_input.c:245)
==1160==    by 0x80489A1: main (parse_cmd_input.c:50)
==1160==  Address 0x40ef02c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==1160==    at 0x40072C5: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==1160==    by 0x8048B28: parse_input (parse_cmd_input.c:239)
==1160==    by 0x80489A1: main (parse_cmd_input.c:50)
```

So its saying the address is reading a zero bytes of a allocated size of 4, and is trying to read 1 byte from it. However, I haven't over stepped the bounds of the array and I am accessing element 0.

I have checked with gdb, and element zero contains a character.

My program doesn't crash, and seems to work fine. But it might cause a problem on a production server.

I am not sure if I am correct here:
Should this be:

```
cpy_input = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char*));
```

or:

```
cpy_input = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

A char is 1 byte, and a pointer to a char is 4 bytes on my system.

The string passed in would be something like this `"25 b"`

```
int parse_input(const char *input)
{
    char *cpy_input = NULL;
    int has_error = -1;

    if(strlen(input) == 0) {
        LOG_ERR("FAILED: Empty string");
        return -1;
    }

    cpy_input = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));

    apr_cpystrn(cpy_input, input, sizeof(cpy_input));
    LOG_INFO("[ %s ]", cpy_input);

    memset(&channel, 0, sizeof channel);
    has_error = get_input_values(cpy_input, &channel);

    free(cpy_input);

    return has_error;
}


int get_input_values(const char *str, channel_t *channel)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t k = 0;
    int upper_flag = 0;

    /* Indicates no digits or command found*/
    channel->lower = -1;
    channel->upper = -1;
    channel->cmd = -1;

#define DIG_BUFFER_SIZE 32
    char dig_buffer_lower[DIG_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char dig_buffer_upper[DIG_BUFFER_SIZE];

    if(strlen(str) == 0) {
        LOG_ERR("FAILED: Empty string");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(dig_buffer_lower, 0, DIG_BUFFER_SIZE);
    memset(dig_buffer_upper, 0, DIG_BUFFER_SIZE);

    LOG_INFO("SIZE %d %d", sizeof(char), sizeof(char*));

    /* Increament and check for digits */
    for(i = 0; i < DIG_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    switch(str[i]) {
        case 32: /* ignore space */
            continue;

        case 45: /* '-' Start upper bounds */
            LOG_DEBUG("Found a '-' check upper value");
            /* Having a second '-' means the string is invalid */
            if(!upper_flag) {
                upper_flag = 1;
                k = 0;
            }
            break;

        } /* switch */

        /* Insert on digits into the lower and upper values */
    if(isdigit(str[i])) {
            if(upper_flag) {
                dig_buffer_upper[k++] = str[i];
                LOG_DEBUG("dig_buffer_upper[%d] %s", i, dig_buffer_upper);
            }
            else {
                /* Add to digit buffer */
                dig_buffer_lower[k++] = str[i];
                LOG_DEBUG("dig_buffer_lower[%d] %s", i, dig_buffer_lower);
            }
        }
    } /* for loop */
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(cpy_input)` is just `sizeof(char *)`, and not the string length. Instead, say:

```
apr_cpystrn(cpy_input, input, strlen(input) + 1);
```

Or better, use a naked `strcpy` or equivalent. Also there's no need to zero out the array with `calloc`, since you're just about to overwrite it anyway. And since `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, you can allocate the array with:

```
cpy_input = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
```

(Think about strings for a minute: You're already at the mercy of having a null terminator at a sensible place, or `strlen` will either crash or return a huge value. Once you trust the result of `strlen`, you are *guaranteed* to allocate enough memory to `strcpy` the string and the null terminator. Alternatively, you can use `memcpy` for a possibly even more efficient copy, since you know the size.)

Comment: @ant2009: I'm glad. Consider storing the string length rather than computing it twice, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe I'm missing something, but your `for` loop will iterate over `0 .. DIG_BUFFER_SIZE-1`, reading from `str[i]`.  I don't see what would cause that loop to break out early, especially since it seems to immediately wrap a `switch`, and so any `break` inside the `switch` would exit the `switch`, but not the `for`.

Your `calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));` correctly allocates storage for the exact length of input.  The code downstream in `get_input_values` doesn't seem to stop if the string is shorter than `DIG_BUFFER_SIZE`.

(I'd love to be proven wrong, but to know, we need to see more code.)

Comment: And @Kerrek is right that your apr_cpystrn() call isn't likely copying the entire string.  So, I think you have at least two problems to fix.